# Reducing size of HTML output by sharing f:selectItems between h:selectOneMenu?

Tags: html, jsf, facelets

Got a page with ui:repeat bound to a list collection like below:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.products}" var="product">
    ....
    ....
    <h:selectOneMenu id="type" required="true" value="#{product.category}">
      <f:selectItems value="#{productcategories}"/>
    </h:selectOneMenu>
</ui:repeat>
```

I have a list of products being displayed binding to a drop down on a product field as above.

It works fine but the number of #{productcategories} is very large, about 500 categories and increasing, so for each repeat the drop down items is output in the HTML file. This increases the file size especially when the product listing is in the 50 items per page, so is there a way I can reduce the size of the output HTML by sharing the h:selectItems among multiple drop downs?

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. That's the nature of HTML. The HTML `<option>` elements generated by `<f:selectItems>` has to go in the `<select>` element generated by JSF `<h:selectOneMenu>` anyway and cannot be referenced from each other's one.

You could consider to render (show/hide) components conditionally in the server side by the `rendered` attribute so that the generated HTML output is less large. You could also consider to turn on GZIP compression on the response in the servletcontainer you're using so that the network bandwidth is saved.

Comment: The show/hide is not an option as I need it rendered. Gzip sounds better but I guess the issue still remains as page size and the number of items increases.

Comment: Then make it an option or just live with it. Gzip should definitely help a lot. It can decrease the response size up to with 70%. In Tomcat for example it's as easy as adding `compression="on"` to the `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`.